# saving the output of a pipe to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

This seems very easy (and it probably is), but I'm having some problems with saving a result of a pipe to a variable.

Let's say this is the output of the pipe:

```
This
is
the
output
of 
the
pipe
```

Which look exactly as I want. However, if I try to store the pipe into variable:

```
var=$(...pipe...)
```

The output of the echo $var will be:

```
This is the output of the pipe
```

Also tried with printf, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: God dammit, I was looking for this for an hour, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Politank-Z as mentioned in the duplicate, it's not the assignment that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment is fine, but you need to quote the variable in echo:

```
echo "$var"
```

It is probably best practice to put quotes on the assignment and write `var="$(...)"`, but it's not actually necessary since word splitting does not occur on the RHS of an assignment.

Comment: Yeah, this exactly, and thread like this already exist, but I just suck at googling :(